# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to call [UITableView panGestureRecognizer]

Tags: uitableview, memory-management, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, ios6

Just upgraded xCode to 4.5.  iOS 5 is still my deployment target, but Base SDK is now 6.0.

Application now crashes where previously it did not.  The project uses ARC.

The offending line is a property call on a UITableView... asking for the panGestureRecognizer (line 3 below).

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];    
        UIPanGestureRecognizer* pgr = [imageTableView panGestureRecognizer];
        [pgr setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
        [pgr setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
}
```

Produces the following error message:

**-[UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1ea38f70**

How is this possible?  Zombie Analysis says that the gestureRecognizer has been released already?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an ARC issue... two different solutions for those interested.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer* pgr = [imageTableView panGestureRecognizer];
    [pgr setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
    [pgr setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];    
}
```

Or

```
[imageTableView.panGestureRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
[imageTableView.panGestureRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
```

Lesson learned, if it can't be possible.... try ARC as the culprit.