# UITableView no longer scrolling using xCode 4.5, deploying on 5.x or 6.0

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios5, ios6, xcode4.5

Deployed project using UITableView for display of images.
Upgraded to xCode 4.5, suddenly my UITableView no longer scrolls.

This occurs both on the device and on the simulator with iOS 5.0 -> 6.0

Additionally, I have found that I can no longer set the number of minimum touches for the PanGestureRecognizer programmatically.
[Other StackOverflow ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569560/getting-exc-bad-access-when-trying-to-call-uitableview-pangesturerecognizer)
In fact, a Zombie analysis reveals that the recognizer has been released.  This could definitely explain the above behavior.  My attempt to set the recognizer is as follows and crashes.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* pgr = [imageTableView panGestureRecognizer];
[pgr setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
[pgr setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
```

Is anyone else seeing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem when moving to iOS6/XCode 4.5.  It seems that the UIPanGestureRecognizer now steals touches from underlying UIScrollViews or UITableViews.

I found a work around for this in the post below.  It's not the top rated answer, so I'll re-paste the content below as well:

[iphone - UIGestureRecognizer prevents UITableView from scrolling in Xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423253/iphone-uigesturerecognizer-prevents-uitableview-from-scrolling-in-xcode-4-5)

I had the same issue: I used to drag my TabGestureRecognizer directly onto the storyboard instead of creating them through code. With iOS6 this now seems to break scrolling.

I prefer adding views, gestures, etc directly onto the storyboard instead of through code.

You can still do this but with two changes:

1) Referencing Outlet Collections
Right-click the GestureRecognizer which is visible to you within the scene's dock.
Clear the section Referencing Outlet Collections

2) Attach the GestureRecognizer to the related view through code

Create an outlet for your GestureRecognizer
Add the following line within the viewDidLoad method:

[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:_tabGesture];

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured this out last week and was planning to add an answer myself.

Comment: Thanks for the check!  You've got to love all of these miscellaneous hidden changes with XCode 4.5 :)